# User.Identity.GetUserId returns user name and not userid in wso2 token

Tags: jwt, wso2, authorization, openid, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server and after generate a token.
When I use the token to call API I get User.Identity.GetUserId() as username which happened to an email in our case and not the unique userId defined.
I want GetUserId should return user id.
The payload I am getting as given below: namid is here userid.

```
{
  "sub": "supriyad19@getnada.com",
  "aud": "z21RCaZ_ehgaO_5mO8YgxkPUdqMa",
  "unique_name": "supriyad19@getnada.com",
  "nbf": 1616692647,
  "role": "Admin",
  "azp": "z21RCaZ_ehgaO_5mO8YgxkPUdqMa",
  "scope": "email openid profile",
  "iss": "https://demo-identity.onblick.com/oauth2/token",
  "nameid": "6ee0b06f-e9e4-4f91-87ea-8c1310e9c505",
  "exp": 1616696247,
  "iat": 1616692647,
  "jti": "9fca536e-d753-4f35-b7b8-95f1384891ce"
}
```

Can any one help me on that.
[image]

```
[Route("Employee/ExportWorkforceToCSV")]
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "HRManager")]
        public async Task<string> ExportWorkforce(ExportRequestModel model)
        {
           var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Here JWT token should provide sub as userId which is uniquely identified id stored in db. User.Identity.GetUserId(); provides the userId and with help of this Id further we make db calls to get details.

Comment: Which attribute of this token do you want to return as User.Identity.GetUserId() value ? AKAIU you want to get the uniqueId of the user object as the sub of the token. Is it ?

Comment: I want "nameid" attribute which is user's unique identifier to be returned when I call User.Identity.GetUserId(). If "sub" value will come as id then we will get this. In WSO2 Claim configuration I tried to change the claim type of "sub" as userid instead of username but still I get email value as sub

Comment: Did you configure `http://wso2.org/claims/userid` as the Subject Claim URI in the Claim Configuration of the relevant service provider? Can you add a screenshot of the service provider's claim configuration section?

Comment: Where is this `User.Identity.GetUserId()` method?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna, We use .Net Web API with C# code. Where each API method is Authorized and we need loggedIn user Id which we get using JWT.  I have added the code in query thread.

Comment: I got to know this is a bug in wso2 5.10 version. it always returns username as subject even though it was defined as userId.